# Generate dynamically JSON whit pyloadfactory in WSO2 ESB API

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I develop an API resource to WSO2 ESB. This resource is a delete method which recives a JSON and has to send that JSON to endpoint.

But WSO2 need to use payloadfactory mediator to send a JSON to endpoint in API resource. Specifically, I recive an array JSON content like this:

```
[{"id":"1"}, {"id":"2"}]
```

I can create a JSON response without array like this:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json"><format>{ "id": "$1"}</format><args><arg expression="$.id" evaluator="json"></arg></args></payloadFactory>
```

But, I don't any idea how use enrich mediator to resolve this problem. I have to add data in JSON dynamically.

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to call your backend endpoint for all the ids in the json array ?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete many entities in the backen endpoint.

Comment: then you can use backend service withing iterator mediator for each ids in your json array

Comment: Have you tried the Script Mediator ? I think it will be easier to use it in your case:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator